# unable to identify tooltip message present for the textboxes in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i am trying to automate the login functionality of a site.I want to verify whether the tooltip is present or not and to capture the tooltip text displayed for the textboxes.The tooltip is displayed when trying to click on the login btn without filling the textboxes.The tooltip text is attached to the input elements via bootstrap javascript.No tilte attribute is present for the textboxes

https://elasticbox.com/login/        is the site address.Any ideas on how to capture the tooltip text .Thanks in advance

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636721/check-if-please-enter-an-email-address-message-appears

Comment: the above link didn't help.i have to check for the presence of tooltip and to capture its text.i need help reg this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bootstrap tool-tip as you commented for @Varun's reply.
This is just the **HTML5 form validation** which comes into action when you put "**required**" as the attribute of textfield.

Make an html file 'test.html' file using the below code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name='form1' post="http://www.google.com">
<input type='email' required placeholder='email address please' />
<input type='password' required placeholder='password please' />
<input type='submit' value='button1' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Herein, when you click on "button1" (after opening the file in browsers like: Chrome, Firefox, etc.), you will see the necessary validation under the textfield(s).

But, there is no possible way to inspect them.

You can, however, use Sikuli/Autoit to check the presence of that validation text, but that again will be a lost cause as the image of the validation messages/tooltip differs from one browser to another.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like developer needs to be consulted for this.
In javascript it seems like the signin button will remain disabled until both values are filled i.e. username and password.

I am not much into javascript, may be you can consult the developer in order to understand this more.
You can refer image below:

[image]

Comment: as i have mentioned in my problem it is a bootstrap js tooltip.they attached the tooltip to the textbox in jquery after verifying whether the box is empty or not.