# In Selenium, how can I test for the validation error balloon for an input type=number element?

Tags: html, selenium

Given I have a web form

And the form has an input element of type "number" and min and max attributes are specified,

When I use selenium to set a value in this text field that is out of range,

and I submit the form,

Then how can I test in Selenium that the validation message balloon has been displayed in the browser?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML representation of an element with the balloon? Thanks.

Comment: that is the point, it is not presented in html. It is a browser feature.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input:invalid")  this is not really my discovery. Found it at http://stackoverflow.com/a/29548873/267540